# Access to SPSS via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, spss

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I have built a data management system in Access, with SQL Server as a backend. I want to provide the following function to my users.

The ability to export the data from the management environment directly to SPSS.
I just need the data (from an ADODB dataset) to be stored in a .sav file.
The data is provided by a dynamically generated query. Also the data is not directly accessible by the users via ODBC or the SQL Server. Therefor it is needed that Access collects the data and stores it in a .sav file.

Has someone already done this, or where can I find good documentation on how to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uhm...maybe you can store it as a access file and run a spss-script, which imports the access file? this is at least possible...

Comment: I know that is possible. And in that case I prefer exporting to Excel. But I want to have a 1 click solution for the users. And preferably I want to also add the variable and value labels for them. Without having them to run a SPSS SYNTAX that can fail.

Comment: In case you haven't seen it already, the thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.stat.spss/sooW_UeORyM) may be of interest.

Comment: I was hoping there would be an easy reference to SPSS with functions that can generate a .sav file. But it seems a bit complicated!

Answer (score 0):

You can always provide a custom dialog for SPSS code.  If the SPSS user cannot use ODBC directly against the database, you could use VB automation between the Access database and SPSS.  This is documented in the VB scripting help, or you could just import the SPSS automation libraries into Access.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the right documentation for the SPSS automation libraries?